# What is `-fsee` in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

I was surprised to find that this flag gave no error:

```
g++ -fsee foo.cpp
```

whereas `-fasdf`, as well as any other unknown flag gives an error. I'm unable to find it in `man gcc` as well as the [online manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html). Try online for [GCC 6.1.0 and 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef16b8018fde8c3d). It also works on 5.3.1 (my machine).

It has a `-fno-see` counterpart like most flags.

Does anyone know what this flag does or where I can find documentation for it?

Comment: NSA knocks on door, "user has been removed" :-)

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++)

> `-fsee`
>       Eliminate redundant sign extension instructions and move the non-redundant ones to optimal placement using lazy code motion ( LCM ).

Other options imply the letters stand for "sign extension elimination":

> `-fdump-rtl-see`
>       Dump after sign extension elimination.

Comment: For reference: Documentation on `-fsee` was removed in 2009 ([commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/doc/invoke.texi?r1=148654&r2=148664&pathrev=148664)) and the revision log makes it look to me like the switch is currently a nop.